Git ветка в режиме Rebasing
В какой то момент вместо merge и cherry-pick решил попробовать rebase, в следствии чего в какой то момент, полезла куча конфликтов, при чем из файлов которые очень давно я не трогал в принципе. Исправлять эти конфликты естественно нет никакой возможности, т.к вспомнить что там к чему уже не возможно.
Ветки dev и main висят в состоянии Rebasing, в dev я поисправлял конфликты тупо заменив файлы на актуальные (взяв их из продакшна). Но все равно висит в Rebasing эта ветка...
Конфликты полезли после
git rebase --continue
но git мне это сам предложил в момент когда я пытался сделать push
$ git push
Enter passphrase for key '/home/toorr2p/.ssh/id_rsa': 
To gitflic.ru:itserw/itserw_chinamarket.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitflic.ru:itserw/itserw_chinamarket.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Я сделал
$ git pull

появились конфликты (которые я поправил)
hint: use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits
hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.skippedCherryPicks false"
Auto-merging .last_version/default_option.php
Auto-merging .last_version/include.php
Auto-merging .last_version/lang/ru/lib/apiclientprovider.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .last_version/lang/ru/lib/apiclientprovider.php
Auto-merging .last_version/lang/ru/lib/product.php
Auto-merging .last_version/lang/ru/options.php
Auto-merging .last_version/lib/apiclientprovider.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .last_version/lib/apiclientprovider.php
Auto-merging .last_version/lib/iblock.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .last_version/lib/iblock.php
Auto-merging .last_version/lib/product.php
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .last_version/lib/product.php
Auto-merging .last_version/options.php
error: could not apply 0fa354c... #21044 - 1. загружать товары только проверенных поставщиков..
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 0fa354c... #21044 - 1. загружать товары только проверенных поставщиков.

Дальше
git rebase --continue
.last_version/lang/ru/lib/apiclientprovider.php: needs merge
.last_version/lib/apiclientprovider.php: needs merge
.last_version/lib/iblock.php: needs merge
.last_version/lib/product.php: needs merge
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add

git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 52635dc
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 0fa354c #21044 - 1. загружать товары только проверенных поставщиков.
Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
   pick 6bdae09 resolve conflict cherry-pick #21262 - добавил новый тип исключения ProductErrorException, поправил баг в классе Vendor
   pick 028f70d #21334 - Исправить ошибку с типом данных boolean для записи логов в файл
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'dev' on '52635dc'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
        both added:      lang/ru/lib/apiclientprovider.php
        both added:      lib/apiclientprovider.php
        both modified:   lib/iblock.php
        both modified:   lib/product.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

И дальше в итоге меня вообще в какой то момент типо из ветки выкинуло что я не мог закомментить resolve conflict
Что это за глюки, можете подсказать как выйти из этой ситуации?

Вы все еще находитесь в режиме rebase, отмените его выполнив git rebase --abort.

так а почему я в нем нахожусь досих пор? если я его сделаю, не потеряю ли я изменения?

Вы в нем находитесь, так как вы его начали, увидели конфликты, и не закончили. Вы потеряете все изменения.
